# Why Outlook plug-in load from .vsto while other uses .dll?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsto

Develop a plug-in for Outlook in Visual Studio using c# and .net(4.0) and creates its installer as describe [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019). It works like a charm. From Outlook Add-ins list all other add-ins are loaded from the DLL file but mine from .vsto file. May I know how to deploy it properly so it also displays the DLL file instead of the VSTO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VSTO for deployment, you will end up with a `.vsto` file that does the registration of the add-in.

You can write your own add-in, using C or C# with COM interop, and then you will end up with a DLL you can register, but personally I would stick with using VSTO. It does a lot of work for you.

More on writing your own implementation can be found in [How to build an Office COM add-in by using Visual C# .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/office-com-add-in-using-visual-c).

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a shim if you want to get your library visible in Office applications. Or just develop an unmanaged add-in (a shim is not required in this scenario). VSTO uses its own mechanism with .vsto files (loaders). The main purpose of such loaders is to create an isolated application domain and prevent any application failures from others.

For example, Add-in Express developed its own shim (adxloader) which creates a separate application domain and loads your add-in there. You can read more about that in the [Isolating Office Extensions with the COM Shim Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa159894(v=office.11)) article.